# drop down list with  multiple check box levels in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I need to create a drop down list that contain multiple checkboxes as well as multiple levels. The user should be able to select an option and/or dig deeper to select sub categorical. See the example from the code below.

So far, I was able to create the drop down list and the check boxes. I am having problems getting the id of the button selected and opening the corresponding div

http://jsfiddle.net/Ammarcola/e5CZb/

How can I get the button working?

edit: I will explain my approach to make the code easier to read. 
I am trying to create multiple  with each of them containing a list of check boxes. Whenever a button is clicked, all the s should .hide() and only the requested  would .show(). I am not worried about how the main  would be reached again, but all the  should reset once the drop down list is collapsed. Hope that helps.

Comment: ID's should be unique - You have button and div set to id=1.. probably are others too but i didn't look too far into the html

Comment: @wirey I didn't catch that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given the corresponding id of the buttons to the Div's that have to be manipulated.. Then finding the button that was clicked and constructing the div that has to be opened..
Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/e5CZb/91/) and let me know if this is what you were looking for .. 
Or is it a different requirement..

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("p").toggle();
     var btnID = $(this).attr('id');

    var coresDiv = $('div#' + btnID);

    coresDiv.toggle();
});
```